# Average of a column, based on equals condition of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want the average of column 'vgain' if the value in the column 'pgain' == 4. Both vgain and pgain are of type int64, with no missing values.

I tried this:

```
df['vgain'].groupby(df['pgain'] == 4).mean()
```

Which gave me the following output:

```
pgain
False    2.851485
True     2.060606
Name: vgain, dtype: float64
```

Is there a way to directly show only the value of 2.060606. Maybe with some other code? I got the value that I wanted to get, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
df.query('pgain == 4')['vgain'].mean()
```

Or

```
df.loc[df.pgain == 4,'vgain'].mean()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, never heard of 'query' before. Thanks a lot!